# How come "wrap_content" pushes up View?

Tags: android, android-layout

Suppose I have

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="36sp"
         />

         <com.example.PieGraph
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="160dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"  
            android:id="@+id/piegraph"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

where the `layout_height` is specified as `160dp`, I get this in the emulator:

[image]

If I change `android:layout_height="160dp"` to `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`, the TextView with '46' is pushed up:

[image]

Does anyone know why? I'm just trying to centre the TextView and the graph vertically.

Thanks!

Comment: You already fixed it with 160dp height..then what you want ..

Comment: for some better result use layout_weight in child views.i think 40:60 what you need here.

Comment: @RanjitPati I'm trying to not specify heigth in dp. I'd like it to take up all the space available depending  on the screen size. That is, for larger screens, I fear 160dp would result in empty spaces.

Answer (score 1):

I would bet that the PieGraph view has a larger layout than 160dp. Thus, when using wrap_content, the layout is pushing the textview because of this extra space the PieGraph has.

Sorry for entering an answer and not a comment. I don't have 50 reputation points yet.

EDIT:

Try activating the "Show layout boundaries" option on the "Developer Options" menu on settings.

Comment: Oh, the boundaries are indeed very useful. Thanks!